# Obtener la fecha actual y mostrarla en un input

Tags: javascript, html

muy buenas tardes.
Estoy haciendo una pagina en la cual al entrar a una pagina que tenga un formulario para llenar muestre un input con la fecha y hora actual o del día.

estuve buscando en varias paginas y encontré una opción, pero al momento de correrlo ya en la pagina no muestra nada, muestro código:

```
 <div>
            <label>Fecha de Ingreso</label>
            <input type="text" id="currentDateTime">//Campo donde mostrar la fecha
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Fecha de Salida</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de salida">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

El codigo que hace el metodo para dar la fecha
[image: Codigo de JavaScript que da la fecha]

El resultado que muestra en la pagina es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 1):

saludos yo lo he probado de la siguiente forma y funciona

html

```
<div>
            <label>Fecha de Ingreso</label>
            <input type="text" id="currentDateTime">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Fecha de Salida</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de salida">
        </div>
</div>
```

el js quedaría asi

```
date = new Date();
year = date.getFullYear();
month = date.getMonth() + 1;
day = date.getDate();
document.getElementById("currentDateTime").value = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
```

si necesitas la fecha y hora puedes de manera directa hacer el js

```
date = new Date();
document.getElementById("currentDateTime").value = date;
```

y con formato y todo puedes hacerlo asi

```
date = new Date();
year = date.getFullYear();
month = date.getMonth() + 1;
day = date.getDate();
hours = date.getHours();
minutes = date.getMinutes();
seconds = date.getSeconds();
if (hours < 10) hours = 0 + hours;
if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;

document.getElementById("currentDateTime").value = month + "/" + day + "/" + year +" "+ hours+ ":" + minutes + ":" +seconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `toISOString().slice(0,10);` y siguiendo la misma lógica que propones, funciona sin problema. En caso de que no funcione en tu código, debe tratarse de algún tipo de conflicto.

`toISOString()` Trae la fecha actual en formato ISO.

`.slice(0,10);` Solo devuelve los primeros 10 caracteres.

```js
var today = new Date();
var date = today.toISOString().slice(0,10);
var time = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

document.getElementById('currentDateTime').value = dateTime;
```

```html
<input id="currentDateTime" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede que el código que tienes no funcione por llamar a los parámetros con algunas palabras reservadas.

El siguiente código debería de funcionar-te ya que no se escogen palabras reservadas...

```
<div>
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Fecha de Ingreso</label>
        <input type="textbox" id="FechaDateTime" value="" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Fecha de Salida</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de salida" />
    </div>

</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Fecha = new Date();
    var Ano = Fecha.getFullYear();
    var Mes = Fecha.getMonth();
    Mes++;
    var Dia = Fecha.getDate();
    var Hora = Fecha.getHours();
    var Minuto = Fecha.getMinutes();
    var Segundo = Fecha.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("FechaDateTime").value = Dia + "-" + Mes + "-" + Ano + " " + Hora + ":" + Minuto + ":" + Segundo; 
</script>
```